# Setting environment variables in a virtual environment during a pip installation

Tags: python, pip, environment-variables, conda

I would like to set environment variables when my Python package is `pip install`ed, so that the user and scripts in the package have access to something like `PACKAGE_HOME` whenever in a virtual environment with my package installed.

I have tried adding the following in `setup.py`:

1. `os.environ['PACKAGE_HOME'] = 'VALUE'`
2. `export PACKAGE_HOME=VALUE` with `subprocess.call`

but realized that these variables do not persist beyond the current Python runtime/current shell session.

For various reasons I currently `pip install` my package into a conda environment (I am aware that this is potentially a bad idea). Conda documentation offers [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables), but I would like to avoid creating a shell script to execute the listed steps and then calling the script from `setup.py`, if possible.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this? I would have thought it common for package installations to set EVs. But so far, having seen that setting venv-persistent EVs from within a Python script is not at all convenient, is this even common/acceptable practice?